# My code for retrieving last tweet date doesn't work properly since yesterday

Tags: javascript, twitter

Before yesterday the following JS code worked fine for retrieving the last tweet and its date :

```
jQuery.getJSON("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/mon_compte_twitter.json?callback=?", function(data) { 

var date = data.created_at;  
var finale = data[i].text;  

var dateTwit = new Date(date);           
var dateAct = new Date();           
var diff = dateAct.getTime() - dateTwit.getTime();
```

Today it works only if the tweet was posted many days ago, but if the last tweet was posted a few minutes or hours ago, its date is negative.

Anybody could tell why?

Comment: maybe coz the date of the tween comes in year/month/day format, and the actual time comes in a separte variable?

Comment: you could display the data variable in your console log so that you can see what data is returning, compare the difference, then tweak your code as needed.

Comment: Twitter API is not realtime.. Please read the API documents fully.. You will understand.. Due to high amount of requests from API, twitter sometimes gives the cached output and i'm sure that's not accurately real time..

Answer (score 0):

> Twitter API is not realtime.. Please read the API documents fully.. You will understand.. Due to high amount of requests from API, twitter sometimes gives the cached output and i'm sure that's not accurately real time.  -@kvijayhari

Well it works now, so I guess kvijayhari was right, thanks kvijayhari !